# Not able to write in redis from spark job

Tags: json, apache-spark, redis

I am creating a scala hashmap and trying to write it as Java  hashmap in redis from a spark job , but it is giving this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
redisson/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeResolverBuilder
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at org.redisson.config.Config.<init> . 
(Config.java:101)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at org.redisson.Redisson.<init> . 
(Redisson.java:113)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at 
org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:154)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at 
com.oto.sims.writers.RedisWriter$.apply(RedisWriter.scala:237)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at com.oto.sims.userfeatureaggregator.usersrecommendation.UserRecommendationAnalyzer$$anonfun$trackRecTypewiseRequests$1.apply(UserRecommendationAnalyzer.scala:158)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at com.oto.sims.userfeatureaggregator.usersrecommendation.UserRecommendationAnalyzer$$anonfun$trackRecTypewiseRequests$1.apply(UserRecommendationAnalyzer.scala:155)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
2018-08-28 10:39:48:: at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at com.oto.sims.engine.UserRecommendationActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UserRecommendationActor.scala:24)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at com.oto.sims.engine.UserRecommendationActor.aroundReceive(UserRecommendationActor.scala:16)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
redisson.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeResolverBuilder
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
2018-08-28 10:39:48::   ... 23 more
```

This is what my Dependencies.scala file has :

```
val commonDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.11",
log4j,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % mysqlVersion,
"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
"org.redisson" % "redisson" % "3.4.2",
"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.8",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.7.9",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.7.9",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.7.9"
```

)

I have no experience in redis .Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the details you provided is not compleete , 
what port number you are using in your Redis Server
what OS  , are you running one computer and virtual machines , or different computers .

**although , you can resolve this issue by checking these points :**

-make sure you are able to ping the server ip

- try to check if the port is opened or not  , you may use telnet on terminal , Nbtstat if you are using windows OS. also check db mysql port
- update jackson lib to to recent version or version number 1.9.13 in case the recent one did not work .